# Word COM doesn't appear to be registered on server for calling from C#

Tags: asp.net, com, ms-word, windows-server-2008

I've developed a web application that uses Word to process template files and save out as PDF. This works fine on my dev machine and on our live server. However, we're changing servers to a 2008Server and after installing Word my app can't access the Word COM object. They don't appear to have been registered. I've checked using DComCNFG.exe and on my local machine, Word is listed in the DCOM Config folder, under My Computer, but on the new server it isn't.

As Word is a .exe and not a dll i can't use regsvr32 on it (I've tried), so how do I get it registered?

(I know moving away from Word would be a good idea and is something I will be looking into in the near future, but for now I need to get the new server running as is)

Comment: I'd guess at a a bitness mismatch - is the server 64-bit? How about the version of word?

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. Yes, the server is 64bit. I'm not sure about Word. But there aren't any Word entries in the COM list. If this was the problem, I'd still expect to see a Word COM entry but have different errors - perhaps mismatched GUIDs.

Comment: Microsoft Word is not a Server based Software. Don't do that.

Comment: I believe that 32-bit and 64-bit COM are kept separate - you'd need to run 32-bit dcomcnfg to determine whether it's registered.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion Damien. I didn't know about the /32 /64 switches for dcomcnfg.exe, but I've run both and neither show Word as registered for COM.

Answer (score 0):

OK, so I've finally got this working after a couple of frustrating days. Many thanks for your suggestions.

Firstly, thanks for the bitness tip. I uninstalled the 32bit version of Word and installed the 64bit version. Then Word appeared in dcomcnfg.exe and I could add my user (NETWORK_SERVICE) to its security permissions list. FYI, prior to installing the 64bit version, running "dcomcnfg.exe /32" and "dcomcnfg.exe /64" gave exactly the same results.

One last thing I had to change was to tick "The Interactive User"on the Identity tab of the properties dialog for the Word COM object in dcomcnfg.